# Change UIPrintInteractionController Navigation Bar Title

Tags: ios, printing, title, navigationbar

How to change the UIPrintInteractionController's navigation bar title (Printer Options)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use UIPrintInteractionController's delegate methods for change appearance of it,

```
- (UIViewController *)printInteractionControllerParentViewController:   (UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController
{
    return self.navigationController;
}
- (void)printInteractionControllerDidPresentPrinterOptions:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController
{
    // self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor redColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];

   // self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor=[UIColor purpleColor];
   self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But, the print controller covers the whole view, I need to maintain the print controller as popover.

Comment: I need to create a popover with navigation controller as content controller. Then, return the navigation controller in the delegate printInteractionControllerParentViewController.

Comment: @Allan: hi, sorry for delay, i was just busy on my work,, is it  solv3e oyur issue?

Comment: tintColor or barTintColor both are not working in iOS7 iPad. Could you please help me, I am NOT using UIPrintInteractionController's delegate. Instead I am using [UINavigationBar appearance] setBatTintcolor];

Comment: why do you return a navigationcontroller in the method that returns a view controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma mark - Print Delegate -

- (UIViewController *)printInteractionControllerParentViewController:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController {

    return self.navigationController;
}

- (void)printInteractionControllerDidPresentPrinterOptions:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController {

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = AppColor;
    self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
     @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
}
```